# Best practice to define the helper functions in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have some helper functions like image compression function in my ios project. What is the best place to define them (considering memory)?

1. as static method inside a class
2. function inside a struct
3. function without any class (outside of class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the approaches has any effect on memory. Code is linked into your executable regardless, and does not affect the size of your objects. You should make your decision based on what makes for the cleanest design.

Functions inside a struct sound like a bad idea unless the functions relate to the hosting struct.

Static class methods can be good for related functions that you want to group together, assuming they are related to the class that "hosts" them. That approach also has the advantage of "namespacing" your function names so you avoid naming collisions. (As others have pointed out, though, making methods class methods purely for name-spacing is probably not a good idea.)

Global functions are good for functions that really are global in scope and don't naturally fall into groups with other functions, but you need to be careful about naming them to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a static function inside a class/struct/enum and a global function is solely the difference in the hoops you have to jump through at the calling site. For example:

```
class Foo {
    static func bar() { }
}

func foo_bar() { }

// call the first
Foo.bar()
// call the second
foo_bar()
```

IMHO Classes are not namespaces and should not be used as namespaces. That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: Don't you mean "Classes are not namespaces and should **not** be used as namespaces"?

Comment: Yes, thank you for that. :-)

Comment: @DanielT. That is what namespaces are for, but Swift doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: Swift *does* have namespaces. It's just that nobody uses them.

Answer (score 0):

The differences should be negligible. You should not use classes as namespaces as well.

I'm posting this answer despite there are perfectly valid answers already available. The point I would like to highlight is that you shouldn't really bother much with any kind of optimizations before you actually hit the problems. Here is a relevant quotation from Donald Knuth:

"Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Although in your case there is unlikely to be any serious problems, whether you do it this way or that :)